# .draggable() id is removed from <li> upon dragging/cloning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was recently forced to upgrade:

- jQuery from 1.7.1 to 1.8.3
- jQueryUI from 1.8.9 to 1.9.2

(I was forced to upgrade in order to be compatible with the latest version of the Blueimp's jQuery File Upload.)

I have the following code, which worked perfectly under (1.7.1 / 1.8.9)

```
$( "div.archive li" )
  .draggable({ // make the archive-icons draggable and connect to the album(s)
    connectToSortable:  handleSortable, // ,"#album_45 ul", //
    helper: "clone", // (helper must be set to 'clone' in order to work flawlessly),
    revert: "invalid",
    appendTo: "body"})
```

and

```
sortableUL.sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: "body",
    update : function () {
        var serializedSequence = sortableUL.sortable('serialize'); // Fails in jQueryui/1.8.21 !!
        $.ajax({
            url: "/callback/upAlbum",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedSequence,
            success: function(htmlData){
                sortableUL.html(htmlData);
                recursiveSortable(albumID, joPanel); // once the newly ordered zone-album has been read, recurse back to: make list sortable & slidable
            }
        }); // END $.ajax
    } // END update : function ()
});
```

The above code works fine under the older jQuery and jQueryUI but fails under the new versions. If I downgrade back to the older version, the code will work again (but then my jQuery FileUploader won't work!).

No error messages are generated in the new setup. However, the following scenario plays out:

The draggable list-tems are `<li id="icon_1234">`. When these are dropped into the `.sortable()`, they are accepted. Thus, they become a `<li>` in the `.sortable()` `<ul>`. However, at that time the `id="icon_1234"` becomes removed. Other attributes of the `<li>` are left in place.

**update:** In fact the `id="icon_1234"` becomes removed when the `<li>` in appended to the `<body>`, so the `.droppable()` is apparently not the cause of the problem. However, commenting out the `appendTo:` option does not change the problem.

Of course, without an `id="icon_1234"`, the newly dropped `<li>` does not survive the below statement:

```
var serializedSequence = sortableUL.sortable('serialize');
```

So, after the update-callback, the newly dropped `<li>` disappears from the `.sortable()` list.

I really have no hunch on how to solve this issue...

Comment: Apparently, this is a new feature (albeit undocumented), as per http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7734 The reasoning seems to be be that one does not want duplicate ID's. Of course, these duplicates ID's were removed by sortable()'s update-callback anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me share what I found, and the slings and arrows that I endured along the way.

It is my understanding that the jQuery UI gods [consider](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7734) the removal of an `id` from a `draggable` when dropped into a `sortable` to be a feature. It seems that this was introduced somewhere between 1.8.9 and 1.9.2.

The reasoning would be be that one does not want duplicate ID's. If so, the `.sortable('serialize')` method should not look for the `id=""` but for some other attribute of the `<li>`. (However, the serialize method continues to look for `id`'s by default.)

So, here is my work-around. Your list items used to look like so:

```
<li id="foo_123">
```

We need to add an attribute to these `<li>`'s:

```
<li id="foo_123" bar="foo_123">
```

Next, we instruct the serialize method to look for the new attribute, rather than the id:

```
var serializedSequence = $('#sortableUL').sortable('serialize',{
  key: 'foo',
  attribute: 'bar'
});
```

This should do the trick. However, in my case there was one more sling/arrow. The `serialize` method did not produce a properly serialized array. (I don't know why, but I can't afford to lose more time on this *feature*.) Therefore, I needed to add:

```
serializedSequence = serializedSequence.replace(/=/g,"[]=");
```

Update: Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTTsB/) that someone else made for a similar solution.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer above by Ivo Renkema, you can use an array push on the key:

```
var serializedSequence = $('#sortableUL').sortable('serialize',{
  key: 'foo[]',
  attribute: 'bar'
});
```

That will produce the array foo[]=1&foo[]=2...

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/juanserrats/nr4azdem/)